# Android - Enabe larger use of RAM

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, ram

How can I enable the app to use more available RAM when needed?

The app has already set `largeHeap = true` for the application, but still fails when I try to download and process a large API response of about 30MB.

Even though I'm streaming the response there seems to be an issue which is independent of this question.

My question though is, why cannot the app use the available RAM of the device (4GB) if largeHeap was already set. How do other apps are able to use GB of ram for a game but a simple app cannot hold 50mb for some seconds?

Comment: So what is the 30MB of API response? Is it a JSON file? How are you parsing it in your app?

Comment: "still fails when I try to download and process a large API response of about 30MB" -- I recommend focusing on optimizing your implementation. "app has already set largeHeap = true for the application" -- how big the "large heap" is depends on the device and the manufacturer's choice. For millions of phones, the large heap is no different than the regular heap, because the device has limited RAM. "why cannot the app use the available RAM of the device (4GB) if largeHeap was already set" -- because that's not what `largeHeap` specifies.

Comment: "How do other apps are able to use GB of ram for a game" -- they are written in C/C++ and use native memory allocations (`malloc()` and stuff built atop it). The heap limits are for Dalvik/ART apps.

Comment: If you're doing a network request, that's the easiest thing to avoid memory issues with.  Write it to disk instead of storing it in memory, and use a streaming parser so it doesn't need to be in memory when parsing it.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you , it is a JSON file however the app is streaming the network request with Retrofit byteStream, then the json is being processed by chunks because it is a list so I can process every item and not the complete list.

Comment: Realistically a new question with your code & OOM error would be better as trying to get a "larger heap" isn't in the cards. You may want to follow @GabeSechan suggestion of download then parse to confirm which part of your code is getting the OOM. At a guess something in your JSON parsing/processing isn't releasing correctly which is why code/error/etc. would be more useful.